# how to see my view instead of json data in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-7

So, I'm trying to retrieve the data using laravel' API. But I only keep getting this JSON data instead of my view with the data from the API. I don't know what I'm doing wrong some help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
This is my controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4); 
        return PostResource::collection(Post::all());
        // return response()->json(Post::get(), 200);  
        // return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Posts</h1>
@if(count($posts)>0)           
            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                @foreach($posts as $post)

                        <div class="col mb-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <img style="width:250px" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}" alt="">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Written on {{$post->created_at}} </p>
                            <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-dark">See more</a> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                @endforeach               
            </div>
        {{$posts->links()}}
@else
<p>No Posts Found</p>
@endif
@endsection
```

Comment: you are returning the `PostResource::collection(Post::all());` and not the view, which seems to be commented out.

Comment: Yes that is true it is commented bc I've been trying out other solutions before I ended up posting it here. I wanted to a way to return a view with a response that is retrieving the data from `return PostResource::collection(Post::all());`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems like you don't need API to populate your view you can simply query in your existing model and return a view.

```
 public function index() {
 $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
 return view('posts.index',['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass Your variable from Controller view

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4); 

         return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

For deatils https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views